# How to move separate Repository to be a project to other Repository

Tags: svn, repository, move

We use SVN Repository with last versions of VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN.
I need your help to change our Repository structure.

We have separate repositories **WBR3FFT** and Altera (see Figure 1).

[image]

We need to move **WBR3FFT** to be below **Altera** repository (see Figure 2).
We need to move it with all its tags folder structure(shown in Figure 1). History log is not so important.
I tried that with dump/load or backup/restore but without success.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [`svnadmin load`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/c/load/) with the [`--parent-dir`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/ref/svnadmin/#svn.ref.svnadmin.sw.parent_dir) option. I.e., generate a dump of WBR3FFT and load it into Altera's subdir.

Update #1:

The command should be as follows:

```
svnadmin load Altera --parent-dir /WBR3FFT -M 256 --file WBR3FFT_dump.txt
```

Note that you need to create an empty directory WBR3FFT before running this command.

Comment: Thank you for help. Please give me full command. For example, this command failed:     **svnadmin load --parent-dir Altera/WBR3FFT -M 4096 Altera < WBR3FFT_dump.txt**.  
    <<< Started new transaction, based on original revision 1       * editing path : Altera/WBR3FFT/branches ...svnadmin: E160013: File not found: transaction'1899-1gx', path /Altera/WBR3FFT/branches

Comment: 1. altera is the name of the repository and you don’t need to specify it in the parent-dir option. 2. you need to create the directory WBR3FFT before you run svnadmin load. I have updated the answer.